# isDirectory returns false for ant task on a folder under svn

Tags: java, ant

Hello i'm running an ant task through eclipse that generates some code but the error i'm getting is on the arguments checking

```
build/classes is not a readable directory
```

relevant code is:

```
if (!destDirectory.isDirectory()) { 
   error(destDirectory.toString() + " is not a readable directory");
}
```

I'm doing this under Windows 7 and the folder is under svn and a shared folder to CentOS with VirtualBox. The directory is created by another ant task that just does `mkdir`.

i'm running has user but with UAC off and has far i can tell there shouldn't be any problems with permissions.

EDIT:

some parts of the ant file:

```
<project name="xpto" default="compile" basedir=".">
  <target name="prepare">
    <echo message="Preparing the project for build..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${classes.build.rel-dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${db.rel-dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.rel-dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>
  <property name="src.rel-dir" value="src"/>
  <property name="build.rel-dir" value="build"/>
  <property name="classes.build.rel-dir" value="${build.rel-dir}/classes"/>
  <target name="instrument-classes" depends="compile">
    <dml-post-processor dir="${classes.build.rel-dir}">
      <fileset file="${dml.rel-file}"/>
      <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
    </dml-post-processor>
  </target>
</project>
```

so i think the path is correct and will use `./build/classes`

EDIT:

```
instrument-classes:
  [echo] Injecting FenixFramework Voodoo Magic...
  [echo] path -> build/classes
```

the output of running `echo` on `${classes.build.rel-dir}`

Comment: Your error message is misleading since [`isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) simply tells us whether a filepath is a directory or not; it doesn't know whether the filepath is readable or not. If a filepath is not a directory, then it is a file (or something else). Try to put a try...catch block when calling it to capture any exception.

Comment: @eee well the problem there is that thats part of an ant task of a framework that i just use the jar. could it be a path problem? updated with more info.

Comment: Are you referring to `<property name="classes.build.rel-dir" value="${build.rel-dir}/classes"/>` when you say `./build/classes`? To confirm the filepath, try to put `<echo message="${build.rel-dir}/classes"/>` before `<dml-post-processor>` section in the `<target>` section.

Comment: @eee done and added to question

Comment: Hmm, try to delete the "build/classes" first under the project root folder. Later, when the Ant task is running, can you confirm physically under the project root folder that the "build" folder is present; if it is present then the "classes" folder is inside it?

Comment: @eee this is done by the dependencies on the ant task, first a `rm` then a `mkdir` of said folders, check the edit.

Comment: Try to create each folder one by one, starting with `mkdir build` and later `mkdir build/classes`. If it is still the same, then I am really not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this problem using a familiar framework (fenix) when using the ant-plugin for eclipse. In fact, the plugin seems to 'run' ant from another different directory.
Still, running ant from command-line (in windows7) seems to work for me.

So, the solution is to use the ${basedir} variable in the build.xml script, for well-defined paths.

example:

```
<property
    name="dir.project.java"
    value="${basedir}/src/project/" />
```

instead of:

```
<property
    name="dir.project.java"
    value="src/project/" />
```

Sorry about an outdated reply.